# finding all linestring's that intersect another linestring in mysql

Tags: mysql, gis, spatial, mysql-8.0, spatial-query

I'd like to be able to identify all the linestring's that intersect a specific linestring. Any ideas how I might do that?

Here's the best thing I can come up with (untested):

```
SELECT *
FROM trains t
JOIN rivers r ON ST_AsText(ST_Intersection(t.SHAPE, r.SHAPE)) <> 'GEOMETRYCOLLECTION EMPTY'
```

Is this the best way to do this or is there a better way?

Comment: *... all the **polyline**'s that intersect ...* Do you mean `MultiLineString`?

Comment: @Akina - no - it's just a single linestring. I'll edit my question to say linestring instead of polyline. There are multiple linestring SHAPEs in the DB but no multilinestring ones

Comment: It is enough `... ON ST_Intersects(t.SHAPE, r.SHAPE) ...`. See [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d134dbf6348d5a87a215e332e222c481). The same with any other GEOMETRY datatype.